# Подключение скриптов в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос. В ASP.NET MVC 4 скрипты можно подключать через файл BundlesConfig.cs и потом на view рендерить их на странице такой инструкцией:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mybundle")
```

Напрашивается вопрос - а чем это лучше традиционного

```
<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Во всяком случае при обычном способе нужно изменять только один файл, а не два как в первом способе

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бандлы подразумевают разделение подгружаемых скриптов на логические части.
Допустим, отдельный бандл для стилей, отдельный бандл для JavaScript'овых библиотек, отдельный бандл для твоих скриптов.
Править нужно только один файл, а не два. При компиляции страницы MVC сам вставит все необходимые теги.